# Firefox OS: Back up and restore user data

Tags: firefox-os

I am trying to upgrade my ZTE Open from FFOS 1.1 to 1.2. According to [the instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/ZTE_OPEN#Firefox_OS_1.2):

> Note that those steps will erase your personal data, so be sure to make a ([backup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites#Backup_the_phone_system_partition)) first.

However, the [backup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites#Backup_the_phone_system_partition) link doesn't really seem to be talking about backing up user data between versions, and I'm not at all sure how I would use those backed up files to restore my data after a successful upgrade.

Does anyone have experience with manual backup/restore between different versions of Firefox OS?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how version safe this is, but I was able to restore my apps and contacts when upgrading my keon from 1.2 to 1.3 using the following adb commands:

```
adb pull /data ./data
adb push ./data /data
```

You might want to look at this link as well: [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/981858)

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't able to restore SMS or calendar data with `adb push` -- no errors, but the data didn't get restored.